# Why is PHP CURL trying to connect over SSLv3 when I specifically indicate it should connect over TLS?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, osx-elcapitan

Environment:

```
Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3
PHP Version 5.6.6
cURL Information    7.38.0
SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.8zd
```

I'm getting the following error when fetching an HTTPS page:

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

According to other SO questions, it sounded like the issue was it connecting over SSL3 instead of TLS, but I'm still getting the error even with the following added:

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

Can someone please help me figure out why I'm still getting the sslv3 error?  It seems like it's still trying to connect over SSLv3 despite being told to connect over TLS.

EDIT:
I've posted a [test script](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e6ec35d9b3c224f33bbc18ffb0288bf7ed75e05) that demonstrates the issue.  Doesn't work in the environment because it doesn't support CURL, but it demonstrates the issue.  Note that I uploaded the code to my production server, and the code runs fine there resulting in the expected `301 Moved Permanently` response.  But locally, I get this:

```
RESULTS: CURL error fetching url https://seo.com: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure EOM
```

EDIT:
Executing curl from the command line seems to work fine. It's when executing using PHP CURL that I get the error.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192953) problem? (ie the curl bug)

Comment: No, not the issue.  I tried the command they were executing from the command line and it connected without issue over TLS.  In fact, I tried the same URL I'm trying from PHP CURL in the terminal and it works fine there connecting over TLS 1.2.

Comment: I'm not convinced that is the problem. SSLv3 and TLSv1.0 are very similar so it might just be a result of that. OpenSSL 0.9.8 version doesn't support any newer TLS version than 1.0 and curl has disabled SSLv3 by default completely since 7.39.0...